# Merge the values from two Collections using Java

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, merge

I have two `Collections` with values such as the following:
Collection 1 =`[Balance, OrigYear, OrigRate]`
Collection 2 =`[Sum, Count, Avg]`

I want to merge the values from two `Collections` into a single `Collection` or `ArrayList`, which will have a output like `[Balance Sum, OrigYear Count, OrigRate Avg]`.

Could some one please suggest something using Java, as I'm naive user in writing code using Java?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: I tired Stringbuilder ... But i know that is not the right option.

Comment: Maybe your looking for a Map ...

Answer (score 0):

If your lists have different size then result will gather only paired (between two lists) values. However you can modify below code to align lists size by adding empty strings in smaller list.

```
List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("Balance", "OrigYear", "OrigRate");
List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("Sum", "Count", "Avg");
List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(list1.size(), list2.size()); i++) {
    resultList.add(String.join(" ", list1.get(i), list2.get(i)));
}
```